# Reach Agreement With

Tags: ellipsis, subjects, indirect-objects

The phrase "reach agreement" means that all participants agree something, not just one individual participant  So, in this:

> [link](http://www.cnbc.com/id/101823006)
>   Tichelman was arrested on July 4 after police said ***a detective*** lured her back to the Santa Cruz area by posing as a potential client and ***reaching agreement*** on a price of more than $1,000.

, could "a detective ...*reaching agreement*"  be wrong, because only one party is explicitly mentioned as having reached agreement?  Would "a detective ...*reaching agreement* ***with her***" be better?

Comment: Why would both parties have to be explicitly mentioned when the context is completely clear? When I buy something, I always buy it _from_ someone. So if I say _I bought a bread_, you would find that wrong, because it should be _I bought a bread from the baker_? I talk to someone, but saying _I stayed up all night talking_ is _wrong_, because I do not tell you who I was talking to?

Comment: @oerkelens I bought a bread is wrong, but for a different reasin. "Bread" is always uncountable - it's not like "cake" which can be countable or uncountable.  "I bought bread" is fine, "I bought a loaf of bread" is fine, "I bought a bread" is not fine.

Comment: @NigelHarper - I stand corrected. I fell for a weird habit of English there.

Comment: There are a lot of native English speakers who insist of usages that they consider "correct," such as not using the phrase _comprised of_ to mean "_composed of_. However, when describing language usage, there is no such thing as correct. If everybody wants to use banana to mean apple, then it is not wrong and it is not "better" not to do so. If someone, any one, only one, person wants to say _John considered 15 alternatives and then reached agreement,_ who am I to dictate to that one person how to use language?

Answer (score 1):

According to the sentence, two parties reached an agreement: the detective (who had been posing as a potential client) and the prostitute. Although adding "with her" would be grammatically correct, "with her" is implied.